# Vuex getters in computed properties showing undefined until full page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to create computed properties using data pulled with the mapGetters function in vuex, but I'm always getting undefined, until the page/dom fully loads.

Here's an example for an isRegistered computed property that I use to hide/display certain buttons.

```
computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['solos', 'user']),
      isRegistered () {
        return this.solos.registered.indexOf(this.user._id) !== -1
      }
}
```

Here is the HTML for buttons that use the isRegistered computed property.

```
<a href="#" class="register-button" v-if="!isRegistered">REGISTER NOW</a>
<a href="#" class="registered-button" v-if="isRegistered">REGISTERED</a>
```

I'm setting the getters via an action which I'm calling in the created function

```
created () {
      this.getTournament('solos').catch(err => {})
}
```

Here's my action for setting the corresponding getters

```
getTournament: ({commit}, type) => {
    return feathers.service('tournaments').find({
      query: {
        type: type,
        status: 'registering'
      }
    }).then(tourney => {
      commit(type.toUpperCase(), tourney.data[0])
    })
}
```

Here's the corresponding mutation

```
const mutations = {
  SOLOS (state, result) {
    state.solos = result;
  }
};
```

Here's the corresponding getter

```
const getters = {
   solos (state) {
     return state.solos
   }
}
```

The issue I'm having is the value is initially showed as undefined until the PAGE/DOM is fully loaded, causing .indexOf to throw the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to use an if statement on the computed property that checks if the state data has loaded yet.

```
isRegistered () {
  if (this.solos._id) return this.solos.registered.indexOf(this.user._id) !== -1
}
```

This doesn't seem like a proper way of doing things. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the proper way of doing things. Javascript is defensive, you have to check if objects are in place before accessing inner object properties.

Comment: Your last bit of code is pretty much exactly how you should do it.

Comment: Okay, thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 12):

The issue is probably about the vue lifecycle.

At the [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) hook, the computed properties, watchers and data of component are initialized (runs **synchronously**), but *solos* getter runs inside a promise (runs **asynchronously**), so the lifecycle continue without the promise get done.

When *created* hook is finished, the watchers was created, which means if data get changed, they will be reflected at the DOM, but *only* after the promise returns the result, the solos will be filled. So at the initialization of the app, the promise is not ended, but as soon it ends the data is updated and displayed.

A way to avoid this error is to use `v-if="solos.registered"`, but I'm still searching for a better way to solve this.

Comment: Did you find any better way of doing this? @tomurlh

Comment: No but v-if exists for a good reason, so considering that it fits well for that case, it can be considered a proper solution