# Vuex Getters Come Back as Undefined

Tags: vuejs2, store, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm having a Vuex getters issue where the gitters return as undefined (in the Vue Dev Console and no errors are logged in the Chrome Dev Console).

If `mapGetters()` is commented out (like the example code below), the returned data is displayed on screen -> Providing if the user clicks into the link that has the data. The data will NOT display if the user enters the app directly at the point where the data should display.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44186482/742030) but there is no accepted answer

**Vue Console Logs:**

> STATE:
>
> $_lgdHRS:Object
>
> totHrs:129
>
> ---
>
> GETTERS:
>
> $_lgdHRS/totHrs:undefined

**SomeContainer.vue**

```html
<script>
import store from '../../_store'
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('$_lgdHRS',{
      totHrs : 'totHrs',
    }),

  // ...mapGetters('$_lgdHRS',{
  //    totHrs  : 'totHrs',
  //    airHrs  : 'airHrs',
  //    picHrs  : 'picHrs',
  //    pmcHrs  : 'pmcHrs',
  //    voHrs   : 'voHrs',
  //    trngHrs : 'trngHrs'
  // }),
  },

  created() {
    this.storeKey = '$_lgdHRS';
      if (!(this.storeKey in this.$store._modules.root._children)) {
        this.$store.registerModule(this.storeKey, store);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('$_lgdHRS/getLogSummary');
  },
}
</script>
<template>
    <total-summary :hours="totHrs" />
</template>
```

**state.js**

```js
export const state = {
  totHrs: Number,
}
```

**getters.js**

```js
const totHrs = state => state.totHrs;
export default {
  totHrs,
};
```

**mutations.js**

```js
const
TOTAL_HRS_UPDATED = (state, totHrs) => {
  state.totHrs = +totHrs;
};
export default {
    TOTAL_HRS_UPDATED,
};
```

Comment: Also, could the data be not displaying on the initial view have something to do with the `lifecycle` and only displays when entered from another route state??

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because you have just displatched the request in mounted and before the data is set into the state variable your component is displayed.
Hence you can trying using async await in mounted as well as in store actions.
Do refer the following link and check the last example in this.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was nesting my variables as I usually would in other frameworks.

Example:

```js
// NESTED VARS
const r = response
      totHrs  = r.total,
      airHrs  = r.airborne,
      picHrs  = r.PIC,
      pmcHrs  = r.PMC,
      voHrs   = r.VO,
      trngHrs  = r.training;

// CHANGE TO:
const r = response
const totHrs  = r.total
const airHrs  = r.airborne
const picHrs  = r.PIC
const pmcHrs  = r.PMC
const voHrs   = r.VO
const trngHrs = r.training
```

I don't know enough to why but your input would be greatly appreciated in the comments.